# Can two singular matrices ever be row equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Since they are singular, they have a zero row when theyre in rref form, so they will not have any solutions (inconsistent linear system). Thats the extent to which i understand. I am not sure if they can be considered row equivalent when they dont have solution(s).

Comment: Yes, a singular matrix is row equivalent to itself.

Comment: Just because a matrix is singular doesn't mean that the corresponding system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ will not have a solution. For example, $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ will have solutions for every $\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, is it possible for a singular matrix to be row equivalent to a different singular matrix too?

Comment: Right, i forgot that it can be entirely zeros and not just pivot point on the rightmost column

Comment: You appears to have confused “inconsistent” with “underdetermined.”

Answer (score 0):

To find an example, start with a singular matrix that's already in rref form and do a row operation on it to make another singular matrix that is row equivalent to it.

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then both $A$ and $B$ are singular and they are row-equivalent as well because their rref will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a row operation on a matrix $A$ is the same as multiplying it with an elementary matrix $E$ in the front. ($E$ being  the matrix obtained from the identity matrix by the same row operation).

And this matrix $E$ is always invertible (the row operation is reversible/can be undone with opposite row operation).

So $A$ and $EA$ are  row-equivalent. This is  irrespective of whether $A$ is singular or not or whether $Ax=b$ is inconsistent or not (for whatever vector $b$).

If $A$ were singular $EA$ would be singular too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.  Start with any singular matrix and perform row operations on it to get it in RREF.  At each step along the way, you produce a different matrix that is row-equivalent to the original one.